# Is it possible to pass a setState function as an argument to another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Right now, I have a lot of my auth functions inside my screen components and I want to extract them into a handlers file. But, they rely on setting the state for some loading and results states.

How can I properly pass a setState as an argument to a function?

```
const handleSignIn = async (email: string) => {
  setLoading(true);
  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
    email: email,
  });

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setLoading(false);
  } else {
    setLoading(false);
    navigation.navigate('VerifyOtp', { email: userEmail });
  }
};
```

So in this case, I want to refactor the function so it takes another argument of `setLoading` for example. How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to pass just callback as in another answer, but I would prefer another way of doin this:

```
function useSignIn() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSignIn = useCallback(async (email: string) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
      email: email,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      navigation.navigate('VerifyOtp', { email: userEmail });
    }
  }, [setLoading]);

  return [loading, handleSignIn];
}
```

By the way, I'm not sure what `{ email: userEmail }` is. Is `userEmail` misprint (should be `email` instead) or some global variable or comes from another hook? It should be somehow handled in `useMemo` deps.

Comment: Typo on my part when I was writing this up, it should be just email.

Comment: "loading" is used in my component as a prop to the button to display a loading spinner when true. In this example, I wouldn't be able to pass loading as a prop if it's another file?

Comment: @Vik, you can use `props.loading || loading` to pass into spinner.

Comment: appreciate your help. One last thing is I'm not sure how to handle this error. Here is the screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/e8T3DlC

Comment: @Vik, it should've been `useCallback` not `useMemo`. My mistake. Updated an answer.

Comment: The return should be in { } and not [ ], only thing I had to edit. Thank you again. @Qwertiy

Comment: @Vik, both are fine depending on expected use.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own custom hook and extract it into its own file

```
function useAuth() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function signIn() {
    setLoading(true);
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
      email: email,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      navigation.navigate('VerifyOtp', { email: userEmail });
    }
  }

  return [loading, signIn];
}
```

Comment: I've made almost the same solution...

Comment: @Qwertiy nice, arguably a better one with `useMemo`

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way to go is dependency injection.

```js
export const handleSignInFactory = (setLoading) => {
  const handleSignIn = async (email: string) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
      email: email,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      navigation.navigate('VerifyOtp', { email: userEmail });
    }
  };

  return handleSignIn;
}
```

Now in your react component:

```
function MyComp(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const handleSignIn = handleSignInFactory(setLoading);
  // ...
  return <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</button>;
}
```